# Where can I download Krieg The Psycho?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've searched the net on how to get him and I found that I can get him for $10. However, they did not specify exactly *where* and *how* to get the new player.

How do I get a hold of him?

Comment: how is this off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Krieg the Psycho is a downloadable character that will need you to buy the Borderlands 2 Psycho Pack. ([Steam link here (PC only)](http://store.steampowered.com/app/230090/), [XBox 360 link here.](http://marketplace.xbox.com/Product/Psycho-Pack/bd064173-4745-4e29-a84e-d2d41409f337))

Once you have the DLC installed, you will have access to the character in-game.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks for your advice! Plus, there is a 66% OFF offer right now! HELL YEA

Comment: @DavidToh Note that I think you need to have the game itself on Steam as well, to use that DLC

Comment: Oh.... Does Xbox count?

Comment: @DavidToh No, that is PC-specific platform. For Xbox you will need to check a retailer that sells it or check the Xbox store (assuming there is one, I'm a PC only player myself)

Comment: Oh never mind then

Comment: @DavidToh [Here](http://marketplace.xbox.com/fi-FI/Product/Psycho-Pack/bd064173-4745-4e29-a84e-d2d41409f337) seems to be the same DLC for Xbox360.

Comment: @DavidToh If you like 3ventic's answer and find it to have adequately answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.